# Specify absolute address for symbol placement

Tags: linux, linker, ld

I have a static library that I compiled, and when I create executables I want a certain function I created in the library to always be placed at a fixed absolute address.

Specifically, my static library is a set of x86 assembly routines, and I want one of the routines (called _start_exec) to always be located at a fixed virtual address when the ELF binary is loaded. I have tried looking at --defsym, although I don't think that was what I wanted. I don't want to mess with the starting point of the executable, I just want for a certain sequence of instructions to always be located at a fixed virtual address in all executables I link.

Comment: It probably cannot be done in the library file `libfoo.a` alone. If you really want that, you'll need to define your own linking procedures. (`ld` is actually scriptable, if you want it hard enough). And you should motivate and explain your bizarre requirement (there could be a way to avoid it).

Comment: Can you point me in the direction on `ld` scripting uses, examples, etc? My requirement is set; I call a system call that does a similar operation as exec, and I need to call the sys call from a trampoline segment of code so that when the new memory image is loaded, the instruction pointer will always be pre set to the correct instruction. One way around it would be to modify the %eip register in the sys call, but that does not fit within my model.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, you probably need to make an `ld` script. See the *binutils* documentation on [linker scripts](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts)

Answer (score 1):

You can script `ld` to do what you want with `ABSOLUTE(expr)` and `ADDR(section)`. From the `ld` documentation:

```
    SECTIONS { ...
      .output1 :
        { 
        start_of_output_1 = ABSOLUTE(.);
        ...
        }
      .output :
        {
        symbol_1 = ADDR(.output1);
        symbol_2 = start_of_output_1;
        }
    ... }
```

You can modify the script above to suit your exact need.